# What is the difference between Policy Target and Rule Target in ALFA or XACML?

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, alfa

XACML allows us to specify `<Target>` tag in both `<Policy>` as well as in `<Rule>` tags.

What I would like to understand is that:

- What is the utility of having these at both levels?
- What is the individual effect of both of these methods?
- How and when one should use them together or separately?

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a `Target` in `PolicySet`, `Policy`, and `Rule`. They all achieve the same thing i.e. restrict the scope of the element (`PolicySet`, `Policy`, or `Rule`).

Your question should be more around why the three elements? it's actually a way to *divide and conquer* your authorization challenge. Imagine you're tackling authorization for an entire bank. You might have a policy set that focuses on the *retail part* of the bank and another that focuses on the *commercial side* of the bank. You would have an attribute in the target of the `PolicySet` element that would distinguish between retail and commercial.

Inside the retail bank `PolicySet` you could have another series of policy sets or maybe just policies where the `Target` would distinguish between different applications. Inside each `Policy` element you could have `Rule` elements that would have targets that would distinguish between functions of the applications.

HTH